# Can I reuse url path mapping easily in springboot as a setting?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have three methods with `getMapping` annotation in this code.
Actually, I have more methods. 
They are repeated. So I want register these urls as a setting.
There is a good way? Then let me know that.

```
package refill.station.controller.user;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class MemberController {

    @GetMapping("id")
    public ModelAndView id(ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("user/id");
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("pw")
    public ModelAndView pw(ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("user/pw");
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("signUp")
    public ModelAndView signUp(ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("user/signUp");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean as a setting? In a properties file? Or somewhere shared in java code?

Comment: I want to config them at somewhere shared in java code - @greyfairer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are annotations, so you cannot use local variables for that. You can use constants, however, like

```
public static final String ID_PATH = "id"
public static final String PW_PATH = "pw"
public static final String SIGN_UP_PATH = "signUp"

@GetMapping(ID_PATH)
public ModelAndView id(ModelAndView mav) {
    mav.setViewName("user/"+ID_PATH);
    return mav;
}
```

You can also use property placeholders, e.g. when `foo.bar` is defined in application.properties:

```
@GetMapping("${foo.bar}")
```

In general, you should consider if this is really necessary? Are you using those paths in a lot of places? If not, best not to make this more complex than needed.